# What are the best practices for one time production updating database (data migration) from microservice (without manual action)?

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, cron, database-migration

Context : I added a new field to the database and now want to fill it with data.
I need to it once for entities, that were created before this change (now the value of this new field is null, obviously). - data migration as I used to call it.

I use : Java11, SpringBoot3, Postgres.

The question are :

1. what are **the best practices** to do it without manual action? / what are **the best practices** of running data migration task?
2. How this problem is called? Most of the time data migration is used in context transferring data from one db into other.

What came to my mind : cron task ( but we need to set specific time to run this task)

Update :

The value, that I should insert is unknown - I should somehow calculate it ( i should run some business logic, interact with other ms, and so on)

Comment: May be ApplicationRunner/CommandLineRunner?

Answer (score 1):

Use a [database migration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schema_migration) tool such as [*Flyway*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyway_(software)) or [*Liquibase*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquibase) to manage [SQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL) scripts and, optionally, executable code.

The tool tracks which scripts have been run. From that history the tool determines which scripts still need to be run, and then automatically runs them.

You asked:

> How this problem is called?

[*Database refactoring*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_refactoring).

Comment: Hi! thnx for an answer, nut i do not know what data i should insert, as it should be calculated. I updated the question.

Comment: @Lilia And how will you make that calculation? Won’t you use SQL scripts and/or Java code?

Comment: i have to entities. Company and X.  Entity X should have an id of a related company. Company id is a new field, that i added to database of X object. To get CompanyId I should create it with other ms, based on the fields of X object. So yes, i have to use Java code